# How to convert ssd_resnet_50 tensorflow checkpoint to .tflite?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to convert the ssd_resnet_50 model from the tensorflow [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) to .tflite format but it doesn't work.

**Some background**:

1. I'm able to successfully convert the out of the box and retrained `ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized` model to `.tflite` and run the .`tflite` model.
2. Because the s`sd_resnet_50` model is not quantized, I've added the following to the `ssd_resnet_50` `pipeline.config` file and retrained the model:

```
graph_rewriter {
  quantization {
    delay: 48000
    weight_bits: 8
    activation_bits: 8
  }
}
```

After retraining `ssd_resnet_50`, I try to convert the model to `.tflite` format with the following commands:

```
# Produces tflite_graph.pb
python3 object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py \
        --pipeline_config_path=pipeline.config \
        --trained_checkpoint_prefix=model.ckpt-50000 \
        --output_directory=$OUTPUT_DIR \
        --add_postprocessing_op=true

# Produces detect.tflite
bazel run -c opt tensorflow/lite/toco:toco -- \
    --input_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/tflite_graph.pb \
    --output_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/detect.tflite \
    --input_shapes=1,640,640,3 \
    --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \
    --output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'  \
    --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
    --mean_values=128 \
    --std_values=128 \
    --change_concat_input_ranges=false \
    --allow_custom_ops
```

Normally, `TOCO` would produce a valid `detect.tflite` that could be run. However, `TOCO` runs into the following error regarding quantization and Relu6.

Can anyone help?

---

**Error :**

```
2019-05-21 10:41:07.885065: F tensorflow/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:1718] Array WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor_2/BoxPredictionTower/conv2d_0/BatchNorm/feature_2/FusedBatchNorm_mul_0, which is an input to the Add operator producing the output array WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor_2/Relu6, is lacking min/max data, which is necessary for quantization. If accuracy matters, either target a non-quantized output format, or run quantized training with your model from a floating point checkpoint to change the input graph to contain min/max information. If you don't care about accuracy, you can pass --default_ranges_min= and --default_ranges_max= for easy experimentation.
run_toco.sh: line 25:  3280 Aborted                 (core dumped) bazel run -c opt tensorflow/lite/toco:toco -- --input_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/tflite_graph.pb --output_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/detect.tflite --input_shapes=1,640,640,3 --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor --output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3' --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --mean_values=128 --std_values=128 --change_concat_input_ranges=false --allow_custom_ops
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your error it seems that the array `WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor_2/BoxPredictionTower/ conv2d_0/BatchNorm /feature_2/FusedBatchNorm_mul_0` from `WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor_2/ Relu6` does not have min/max information which is needed to do post-training quantization.

You can look at [*Use "dummy-quantization" to try out quantized inference on a float graph.*](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples) section for an example and some details.

You can add `--default_ranges_min=0  --default_ranges_max=255` to your command but you will lose accuracy doing so.

```
bazel run -c opt tensorflow/lite/toco:toco -- \
--input_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/tflite_graph.pb \
--output_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/detect.tflite \
--input_shapes=1,640,640,3 \
--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \
--output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'  \
--inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
--mean_values=128 \
--std_values=128 \
--default_ranges_min=0 \
--default_ranges_max=255 \
--change_concat_input_ranges=false \
--allow_custom_ops
```

From the [Tensorflow Converter command line reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_reference) :

`--default_ranges_min, --default_ranges_max`. Type: floating-point. Default value for the (min, max) range values used for all arrays without a specified range. Allows user to proceed with quantization of non-quantized or incorrectly-quantized input files. These flags produce models with low accuracy. They are intended for easy experimentation with quantization via "dummy quantization"